# Photoflash Capacitor Alternative

Tags: capacitor, alternatives, vintage

I have a very old (mid-60s) photographic flash system, and cannot find replacement capacitors.

Specs:

525 uf, 450VDC

I would assume I can find an alternative range of capacitor, but do not know how to go about this.

Any thoughts? Further info can be provided, just not sure what is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you change the flash design, you will need capacitors rated 450 volts or higher. If your flash uses two capacitors connected in parallel, you can use one capacitor rated close to 1000 uf. If only one is used, you can use two in parallel rated about 250 uf each. If the total capacitance is much higher, there is some risk of damaging the flash tube or the firing circuit. If it is lower, the flash will not be as bright.

Capacitors that are not rated for flash duty would be at risk of damage due to the high discharge current. Capacitors not advertised as photo flash capacitors are probably not rated for that duty.

The capacitors you want are available as new old stock (NOS) on ebay. Capacitors don't have a good shelf life, so those could be pretty risky. If you were to try those, they should probably be reformed. Search online for "capacitor reforming procedure."

Answer (score 1):

Caps that are "charge and discharge proof ' are good and so are : photoflash caps "'So these are your best options .If you cannot or willnot do this then there are a couple of bodges that can work .First use a paralell combo of metal film caps if you have them on hand and if they will fit .You still need the microfarads and the voltage because we are talking joules here .They do make metal film caps 500V at 100microfarad .I am prototyping a PFC dc bus using samples of them .Otherwise if you paralell a large number of small electros to make your 525 microfarad you will get your reliability .Small value electros have lower ESR relative to thier microfarads.This practise is nothing new ,it is common on SMPS.